# Block specific URLs / URIs in browser, like the file:// protocol and other from being visited - How to set Browser policies

Tags: browser, url, uri

How to block specific Uris or Urls in a browser? For example I don't want the `file://` protocol can be visited or other specific locations by the user. Can I also add other policies and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be easily done by customizing browser policies. I will use Chrome and Firefox as examples on a Gentoo Linux system, but this will also work with Chromium-like browsers (such as Brave) and on other operating systems. Please note that the path may vary on other Linux distributions, and the keys may differ on other operating system families such as Mac or Windows. If you are using Windows or Mac, please refer to the original documentation for [Chrome policies](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/) or [Firefox policies](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md).

For Linux and Chrome, I will place a .json file in `/etc/brave/policies/managed/`. If the directory doesn't exist, create it. The file must follow the following structure:

```
{
    "[policy name]": [value]
}
```

For example, the file in `/etc/brave/policies/managed/<filename>.json` could look like this:

```
{
"IncognitoModeAvailability": 1,
"URLBlocklist": [
    "https://facebook.com",
    "file://*",
    "javascript://*",
    "ws://*",
    "wss://*",
    "ftp://*",
    "mailto:*"
],
"DefaultGeolocationSetting": 2,
"DefaultNotificationsSetting": 2,
}
```

This blocks the specified URIs/URLs, deactivates the browser's Incognito mode, and sets the notifications and geolocation settings to false. You can check if the settings were successful by visiting chrome://policy or brave://policy/, depending on the Chromium-based browser you are using. For further options or other operating systems, please refer to the policy documentation: https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/

On Firefox, the process is very similar. Place a file named `policies.json` in `/etc/firefox/policies`:

```
{
  "policies": {
    "BlockAboutConfig": true,
    "WebsiteFilter": {
      "Block": ["<all_urls>"],
      "Exceptions": ["https://security.stackexchange.com/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

This blocks all URLs except security.stackexchange.com and its sub-sites, and blocks the about:config page. If the policies were set successfully can be proved by visiting `about:policies`

Of course, if configuring for non-private use, it's recommended to block all sites at first and then define the allowed sites. For further documentation or if on another operating system, please refer to the official Firefox policies templates on GitHub: https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md

Please note that this approach prevents the user from accessing content via the configured browser. The protocols are still available on the system and must be configured separately.